# Macro to save file to folder depending on month and customer

Tags: excel, vba, button, create-directory

I have the follwoing code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="U:\sales\Quotes test\" & Range("s2").Value & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

This works perfectly but i'd also like it to do a few more things, i have had a play around with it but i just can't get it to work the way i want it to if its even possible!

I'd like it to save as a .xlsm file AS WELL as the PDF
i'd also like it to save to a folder dependent on the year, month and customer. e.g.

`U:\sales\quotes test` this will be static and always exist.

`U:\sales\quotes test\2020\May\Customer` (dependant on cell value D6 in the sheet)

Now here's the clinker! if the folder for customer doesn't exist i'd like it to first create the folder in the correct year and month depending on when the document was created. And then save a PDF and .xlsm version of the document...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Check out the [CreateFolder method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createfolder-method) of the [FileSystemObject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) and show us what you have tried.

Comment: `Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="U:\sales\Quotes test\" & Year(Date) & MonthName(Month(Date)) & Range("s2").Value & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub`  this hasnt worked the way i wanted it to it just saved the with the filename of hte year and month

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it is unreadable. Line breaks matter in VBA and in comments they disappear. Instead [edit] your original question to add the code there. • Note that you cannot save a file to a non existant folder, so you need to first test if they exist and if not create them (using the method in my first comment). Also include a proper error description as *"hasnt worked the way i wanted"* is pretty useless for us to understand what exactly was going wrong there. Please help us to help you.

Comment: Don't worry. I'll find help somewhere else. Thank you for your time and making me feel more stupid than i already do.